# Error installing Nix on macOS Catalina and Big Sur on FileVault-encrypted boot volume on Mac without T2 chip

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, macos-big-sur, nix

I ran the following command to install Nix on my Mac:

```
sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume
```

And I got the following error:

```
error: refusing to create Nix store volume because the boot volume is
       FileVault encrypted, but encryption-at-rest is not available.
       Manually create a volume for the store and re-run this script.
       See https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sect-macos-installation
```

https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sect-macos-installation says:

> If you're using a recent Mac with a [T2 chip](https://www.apple.com/euro/mac/shared/docs/Apple_T2_Security_Chip_Overview.pdf), your drive will still be encrypted at rest (in which case "unencrypted" is a bit of a misnomer). To use this approach, just install Nix with:
>
> `sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume`
>
> If you don't like the sound of this, you'll want to weigh the other approaches and tradeoffs detailed in this section.

I don't have a mac with a T2 chip, so what do I do?

I found some related [github](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/3692) [issues](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/4289), but no direct answer.

Comment: For later travelers: this question refers to a limitation in the Nix installer that has been resolved since Nix 2.4 (released Nov 1, 2021). This limitation was present late in the Nix 2.3.* series (specifically from Nix 2.3.5 to 2.3.16)--this is probably not the answer you need unless you are installing one of those versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I chose to use the [Use a separate encrypted volume](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sect-macos-installation-encrypted-volume) suggestion as outlined in by [Philipp Haussleiter](https://www.philipp.haussleiter.de/2020/04/fixing-nix-setup-on-macos-catalina/):

> This approach only works if you have a Disk that is formated with APFS (that should always be the case, if your OS is running of a SSD).
>
> You can check this with:
>
> ```
> % diskutil list | grep APFS
>
> …
> 0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
> …
> ```
>
> Create another Volume on your Disk for NIX:
>
> ```
> % sudo diskutil apfs addVolume disk1 'APFS' nix
> Will export new APFS Volume "nix" from APFS Container Reference disk1
> Started APFS operation on disk1
> Preparing to add APFS Volume to APFS Container disk1
> Creating APFS Volume
> Created new APFS Volume disk1s6
> Mounting APFS Volume
> Setting volume permissions
> Disk from APFS operation: disk1s6
> Finished APFS operation on disk1
> ```
>
> Your disk may not be named `disk1s6`. Find the name of your disk with:
>
> ```
> % diskutil list | grep nix
> 4:                APFS Volume nix                      7.7 GB    disk1s6
> ```
>
> Again, your disk may not be named `disk1s6`.
>
> Encrypt disk:
>
> You need to enter a passphrase for the encryption. You have to
> remember that passphrase once – you can add it to your key chain later
> on. After that the disk encryption will start in the background.
>
> ```
> % sudo diskutil apfs encryptvolume disk1s6 -user disk
> Passphrase for the new "Disk" user (672C4CFF-34C6-4407-83ED-294C1C42E161):
> Repeat passphrase:
> Starting background encryption with the new "Disk" crypto user on disk1s6
> The new "Disk" user will be the only one who has initial access to disk1s6
> The new APFS crypto user UUID will be 672C4CFF-34C6-4407-83ED-294C1C42E161
> Background encryption is ongoing; see "diskutil apfs list" to see progress
> ```
>
> Setup Mount Point:
>
> MacOS Catalina does not allow to create folders directly under your
> Root Path `/`. But we can use another method to have MacOS create that
> folder for us. To do this, we have to add an entry into the file
> `/etc/synthetic.conf`:
>
> % sudo bash -c 'echo nix >> /etc/synthetic.conf'
>
> Now, the next time, the system starts, a mount point /nix will be
> created. The next task is to have our Volume mounted at Boot.
>
> Setup Mount:
>
> For the Mount Configuration, we need to the UUID of the Volume. We can
> find this via the `diskutil` tool (again, your disk may not be named
> `disk1s6`):
>
> ```
> % diskutil info /dev/disk1s6 | grep UUID
> ```
>
> We must edit /etc/fstab with vifs:
>
> ```
> % sudo vifs
> ```
>
> (vifs  behaves just like vi, so use vi  commands to edit the file):
>
> ```
> UUID=1D9389C1-5676-4077-88F5-8D5304A0B1A6 /nix apfs  rw
> ```
>
> (Your UUID will be different!)
>
> Reboot. You will get a GUI prompt to enter your encryption passphrase,
> and save it to the keychain.
>
> [image: Encrypted Volume Keychain Prompt After Restart]

I then ran:

```
sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon
```

The `--darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume` option isn't necessary because we have an encrypted volume now.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the only place I could find how to make this work! You should consider getting this on the official docs. Just a note for others: the final installation command is to explicitly do a multi-user install. Single user is `sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --no-daemon`

Comment: The single-user install on darwin is no longer supported:
```Error: --no-daemon installs are no-longer supported on Darwin/macOS!```